# How to create a script that simulates the blinking terminal cursor?

Tags: python, animation, scripting

I try to create a script that simulates the blinking of terminal cursor

```
layout.prop(text,'character')
if text.character
    layout.prop(text,'source_character')

def uptext(text):
if text.character > 0:
blinking = [" ",text.source_character]
character2 = random.choice(blinking)
character3 = character2

text.body = character3
```

but the blinking is very fast, I would like to know how to improve and to correct
[image]

Comment: Here is a Geometry Nodes solution: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/286338/107598

Answer (score -3, accepted):

consider .... pseudo code ...

```
    n = 1 // for slower use 2
    fps = 24 //frames per second .. change to suit you
    timeperiod = n * fps
    if (frame % timeperiod) > (.5 * timeperiod):
       then show cursor 
       else do not show cursor
// frame is the current frame provided by Blender
// fps is the actual frames per second intended for final render
```

Please inspect and correct the pseudo code above

Comment: thanks for the pseudo code, I made this: [link](http://imgur.com/a/nR8Ka), but i want that cursor blinking itself