# I need an animated text for a computer console / typing into a terminal

Tags: animation, text-object

I need help. I want to animate a text, like a computer.

Like if someone were writing something in a computer terminal, but I don't know how to do that.

Please help!

Comment: Yes, this can be done with geometry nodes. I wanted this exact effect.

Comment: and what did u try so far? by the way: it can be done with animation nodes as well.

Comment: Hi, JuanJo 'writing in a computer'  can mean quite a few different looks.. do you mean:  'typing into a terminal'?  .. Could you include an image as a style-guide?

Comment: Yes!..RobinBetts, like typing into a terminal...... and TheLabCat and Chris thank you...I'd like to know if you have info about the  how to do it with animation nodes?

Answer (score 11):

In Geometry Nodes, by animating the *Slice* of a string, you can introduce one character at a time.

This version:

- Animates the *Slice*
- Appends a space to the end of the sliced string
- Transfers the position of the appended space, and puts a *Grid* there
- Blinks the grid-object by scaling it to 0 for every other half-second

[image]

.. which looks like this with a green *Wave* texture, in Camera-space:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh my gosh that's beautiful. Well done, Robin!

Comment: @BlenderMaster15 Thanks! To you and other possible downloaders, I forgot to pack the font in the .blend. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Very nice solution. I don't want to nitpick, but it looks like the cursor is a little bit ahead and the letters appear a little too far to the left. Question about this: Why is the *Position* used as *Offset* for the cursor?

Comment: Ah, never mind. I missed the translation value of the *Translation* node. If you use 0.3 instead of 0.5 for the x value then it looks perfect.

Comment: That's fantastic. Love it! The wave texture finishes it off perfectly.

Comment: Hi. @Blunder.. Thanks! You're right. A true nerd-tree would automate the position and size of the cursor according to font, make it flash to the negative over letters for overt-typing. and have it blink only after a period of inactivity. (That last one really stumps me). I mentally went some way down those rabbit-holes. :) before concluding that the GN/shader trees would wind up too big for a compact answer, and  confuse a response to the original question. ( Not to mention being 3 days late )

Comment: @RichSedman ..if it was one of your answers, it would have the parallax behind the glass of a  crt, (ghosted with age,) a phase-flicker against the 'video camera' shooting it, and a reflection of the propellerhead in its slightly curved surface... :D

Comment: @RobinBetts This is awesome! Nice work. Just one question... how can we make it *wrap* words to a new line? A way to specify the line width, and parse words delimited by spaces would be stellar. But even basic support for pre-formatted multi-line text would be enough. I thought maybe I could paste in a multi-line string, but it didn't work. The String node is new to me - not sure if there's a way to match the newline character and instruct it to go down a line there...

Comment: @RobinBetts I realized that it was the String node that wasn't accepting newline characters, not the content of the datablock itself. So I wrote a super simple Python script to replace the datablock's contents: `bpy.data.node_groups["TermType"].nodes["String"].string = bpy.data.texts["TextDataBlock"].as_string()` I then redid the keyframing of the Slice String node, and in the String to Curves node I changed the alignment from top to bottom, to prevent text lines getting pushed up. [Here's the .blend](https://blend-exchange.com/b/rAW8dgRm/)

Comment: One issue I noticed is that *if center-aligning* the text, its position jitters during playback as the string length changes. Maybe there's an easy fix, or maybe we can just manually type in the spaces to center the text, like back in the day. lol

Comment: @Mentalist Hehe .. interesting one! On my ol' Apple II.. fixed-width font in a fixed matrix of cells.  No half-cell adjustment, so if parity(n chars) <> parity(matrix-width), no perfect centering possible. So you would have to re-center manually every other character ... something like that.. add a space whenever necessary to keep the parity constant?

Comment: Correction: In a previous comment, I meant changed "from bottom to top", not the other way around. Also, regarding centering - there is always the option to center any left-aligned text using a function in the Python script - a function that pads text with space characters on each side before it gets written into the String node. Not the most elegant way, but would get the job done if nothing else does.

Comment: @RobinBetts You're right, no perfect centering in many cases (whether done using nodes or Python or manually typing). But maybe it can be set so that it leans one char further to either the left or right. That is to say, when 7 space chars need to be placed on the left and right of a line of text, it could be instructed on which side to place the 3, and which to place the other 4.

Comment: I've submitted [a feature request](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/R1JL/) to add multi-line input support for the String node. Just an idea to make this aspect of Blender a little more user-friendly. :-)