# How do I animate text

Tags: animation, text-object

I need to animate text for a project I am making. By text, I mean the kind you get in the Shift-A menu.

Example:
[image]

will turn into
[image]

after some number of frames.

Comment: Or perhaps a variation on [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/286376/35559)  ?